# Does Not Converge in Probability?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables, with $\mathbb E(X_1)=0$, var$(X_1)=1$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Prove that $\displaystyle \left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ does not converge in probability.

Comment: If you know the Central Limit Theorem, this should be simple.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to show it without using the CLT:

1. Show that $\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ does not converge in $L^2$.
2. Show that $\left\{\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\mid n\geq 1\right\}$ is uniformly integrable.
3. Conclude.